# code first not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, code-first

I am new to MVC. I am trying to create CRUD for Engineer entity for which I have written following modal class.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="first name required")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("First Name")] 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Middle Name")]
    public string MiddletName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "last name required")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LasttName { get; set; }

}


public class Engineer : Person 
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [DisplayName("Qualification")]
    public string Qualification { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

}
```

Now When I add controller for the Engineer with read/write actions and views with entity framework, my Views(Create/Index/Delete/Details/Edit) for Engineer does include Address class fields. But when I run the project I could see address fields in Engineer Table in backend. where am I getting wrong.

Comment: Try make Address a virtual.

Comment: You made typos to Last and Middle names, in case you didn't see.

Comment: I tried , still didn't work. any suggestions

Comment: I don't understand it, view has address fields and database has address fields. Where is the problem?

Comment: please add Address class's code. You want create relationship, but in CodeFirst has some stitutions. and every these stitution has own database map.